# Cisco 1760 router wont load past rommon

Tags: boot, cisco

after reset to factory defaults("write erase") and writing command "write memory" (by a mistake...just wanted to save config....and forgot that on cisco its "copy running-config startup-config"). Router wont load past rommon now(i see in console error messages):

> loadprog: bad file magic number:      0x0
>
> boot: cannot load "flash:"

But i can manually boot it past that by typing in terminal(via console):

> rommonX> BOOT=flash:c1700-adventerprisek9-mz.123-14.T7.bin
>
> rommonX> sync
> rommonX> i

Router is Cisco 1760, IOS ver is

> Cisco IOS Software, C1700 Software (C1700-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 12.3(14)T7

Comment: superuser.com or serverfail.com

Answer (score 0):

It can either be the flow control on your console app or the actual registers you are using. The registers are kinda like boot settings and if it is set to bypass the stored settings it could possibly go into rommon mode.

> router(config)# config-register 0x2102

0x2142 will cause it to bypass the NVRAM settings

hope this helps